# Not able build ios app on physical device

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10, xcode10.1

When I am running app on simulator its working. But when I am trying to run the app on physical device its showing error: `failed with exit code 1`.

Here is the log:

> CopySwiftLibs
>   /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app
>   (in target: WAStickersThirdParty)
>       cd /Users/alivenow/Desktop/IOS\ app/stickers-master/iOS
>       export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
>       export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
>       export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk
>       builtin-swiftStdLibTool --copy --verbose --sign D8D25B2EC12AA1D3D7CD0A6B9B9BFA88ABAC300D --scan-executable
>   /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app/WAStickersThirdParty
>   --scan-folder /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app/Frameworks
>   --scan-folder /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app/PlugIns
>   --scan-folder /Users/alivenow/Desktop/stickers-master/iOS/WebP.framework --platform
>   iphoneos --toolchain
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
>   --destination /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app/Frameworks
>   --strip-bitcode --resource-destination /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app
>   --resource-library libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib --strip-bitcode-tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip
>   --emit-dependency-info /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WAStickersThirdParty.build/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.build/SwiftStdLibToolInputDependencies.dep
>
> Requested Swift ABI version based on scanned binaries: 6
>   libswiftDispatch.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
>   libswiftMetal.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib
>   libswiftCoreImage.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
>   libswiftDarwin.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
>   libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app/Frameworks/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib
>   libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
>   libswiftos.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib
>   libswiftFoundation.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib libswiftCore.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
>   libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib
>   libswiftObjectiveC.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib libswiftUIKit.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
>   libswiftQuartzCore.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib
>   Probing signature of
>   /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
>   /usr/bin/codesign -r- --display
>   /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
>   /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib:
>   code object is not signed at all
>
> Codesigning
>   /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
>   /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign
>   D8D25B2EC12AA1D3D7CD0A6B9B9BFA88ABAC300D --verbose
>   /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
>   /Users/alivenow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAStickersThirdParty-awzqfhzesbnkweesytfblnqvcnid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WAStickersThirdParty.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib:
>   errSecInternalComponent
>
> error: Failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to do clean with Clean build folder?

The combination keys is:

ALT + SHIFT + COMMAND + K

**OR**

You problem is about Developer Account

Comment: There may be a developer account problem...But i don't know what will be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Clean DerivedData

Path:- Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: No, the DerivedData path is configurable under `Preferences -> Locations`.
You can change from the **Default** path to **Relative** (into the project folder) or to a **Custom** path.

Comment: I tried this also...but same error is coming...Don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the case, but it seems that Xcode exits right after signing your app, probably it has something to do with that. 
When building apps on your physical device you need to correctly set app bundle identifier as in your Apple Developer account. Probably can check that. For extensions too, as for stickers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a problem with your code signing config.

A simple way to check if this is the case is to enable automatic signing and selecting your development team from the project inspector.

If the project then builds correctly and runs on your physical device. You know it was a code signing config issue and you will be able to debug further